# Can't use port 80 on SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube7

The first time when I tried to run SonarQube with root user this fails. Searching in internet I find that the new Sonar should be execute by a non-root user. I created the user sonar with the folow command `useradd -m -s /bin/bash sonar` and I executed `chmod -R 777 sonaqube-7.0`. Then I loggin with sonar user: `sudo su sonar`. When I execute `./sonar.sh console` all works fine. But when I change the port by default 9000 to port 80, this fails. Using the command `netstat -plunt` I check if the port 80 is in use, but the only ports that I use is 22 (sshd), 5432 (postgres) and 25 (exim4).I thinks that this happed because the user sonar has not permission to use the port 80. How cant I use the port 80 with SonarQube?

My current Operating system is debian 9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change port of SonarQube to 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259777/change-port-of-sonarqube-to-80)

Comment: I already read it but I think is not good idea  use nginx or apache to proxy from port 80 to 9000 if this can by done using the sonar config file

Comment: Unfortunately, you **cannot** run programs on port =< 1024 as a non-root user; it is made deliberately impossible by the developers of most Linux distributions. More details will be in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists some ways to allow non-root user use the port 80 and 433, using `iptables` to redirect the port petitions, `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` and `authbind`. The way more easy is`authbind`.

**Use `authbind` to grant one-time access, with finer user/group/port control:**

The [`authbind`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind) ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/authbind.1.html)) tool exists precisely for this.

1. Install `authbind` using your favorite package manager.
2. Configure it to grant access to the relevant ports, e.g. to allow 80 and 443 from all users and groups:

   ```
   sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
   sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/443
   sudo chmod 777 /etc/authbind/byport/80
   sudo chmod 777 /etc/authbind/byport/443
   ```
3. Now execute your command via `authbind` (optionally specifying `--deep` or other arguments, see the man page):

   ```
   authbind --deep /path/to/binary command line args
   ```

   E.g.

   ```
   authbind --deep java -jar SomeServer.jar
   ```

---

This option grants trust to the *user/group* and provides control over per-port access but, AFAIK, supports only IPv4.

These are the links that I used to document me:

1. [allow non-root process to bind to port 80 and 443](https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443/892391?newreg=1445f0712ec54116936beab0e8c7da5b)
2. [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to "privileged" ports on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux)
3. [how to run a server on port 80 as a normal user on linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux/660121)

Answer (score 2):

Your current inability use SonarQube via port 80 is actually due to a limitation provided by nearly all Linux distributions: privileged ports.

All ports below **1024** cannot be listened on by programs executed by non-root users — that is, only the user "root" may run programs that run on these ports. This is to provide assurance that when you connect to an application running on that port, the application is "the real thing" and not a fake put up by a hacker.

Because SonarQube does not allow you to execute it as root, proxying port 80 to a port that is above 1024 that SonarQube is executing on is the only way to get around this limitation.